# C# How do I get all the fields of a specific type from a derived class within the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class NetBehaviour
{
    void setSyncFloat (SyncFloat[] values)
    {
        // Find all SyncFloat fields in the child 
        // class (the one that derived this class).

    }
}
```

How do I go about finding all the fields of a specific type in a class that derived from this class within this very class? It seems a bit tricky and I'm guessing I'll need reflections. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class NetBehaviour
{
    void setSyncFloat (SyncFloat[] values)
    {
        // Find all SyncFloat fields in the child 
        // class (the one that derived this class).
        var fields = GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(SyncFloat));
    }
}
```

`BindingFlags` have been included because I assume you want private fields.

Note that `GetType()` will get the runtime type i.e. the subclass type.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
Gladly `this` in you class will also be of the derived type, enabling you to do `this.GetType()` to receive the explicit most derived `Type` of the object.
You can then use `Type.GetFields()` to receive an array of all fields of that type, that you can iterate.